# How to simulate change of system date/time for testing purposes?

Tags: linux, unit-testing, testing, automated-tests

I use gitlab-ci to run my test suite, in one test I would like to simulate a
change of system date (like, going to the day after) in order to see if
everything works as expected, for example:

- redis keys are deleted (TTL)
- some files are written with a new 'run number' since the date as changed
- date and time calculation are ok
- ...

How do I simulate change of system date/time for unit-testing purposes?

---

**EDIT**: since my code base is in Python, I found [freezegun](https://github.com/spulec/freezegun) and [python-libfatketime](https://github.com/simon-weber/python-libfaketime); the former can probably do the trick for my  Python code, and the latter is more powerful since it is intercepting system calls so theoretically I can use it for testing redis TTL if I start redis after the patches are applied.

Comment: I believe *"Is there a tool for this?"* wanders into off-topic territory. I think the question in the title is better for this post.

Answer (score 0):

You can override `gettimeofday` and `clock_gettime` to return any time you want. However, that would not affect pthread waiting functions with timeouts.

Answer (score 0):

How about not picking the Date from System and providing a Date from a Variable you can change by a Script ?

Comment: this would not work for external software I am using, like Redis: the best would be to change the system time for all applications, otherwise for my own code I found 2 projects I could use (see edited question)

Answer (score 0):

When writing a (unit) test suite, you need to clearly define the system under test and its boundaries. In this case your application belongs to the system under test, redis does not.

Things which do not belong to the system under test should be mocked. For python start here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html

Comment: My Python project interacts with redis, and set some TTL on redis keys -- I want to test the behaviour of my software after some keys are deleted because TTL limit is reached. I thought the easiest were to change system date/time, and in fact python-libfaketime does it for me

Comment: You need to mock the redis connection classes in your test suite. Your test suite does *note* test if the redis library does properly set the TTL, only how your application reacts on it. To be clear: Your test suite should never talk to a real redis db

Comment: I disagree, I have a test redis db and I prefer to test the real thing than mocking this part

Comment: Then you have an integration test in mind, not a unittest.

Comment: You're right. I will edit the question title to make it more general